# Get the No of Pending, Accepted and Rejected Users from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables namely register and expressinterest

Where register table contains (user related columns) some are -

```
i) matri_id (unique but not primary)

ii) mobile

iii) email

iv) last_login
```

and expressinterest table contains data related to the matches details where columns are namely

```
i) ei_sender

ii) ei_receiver

iii) ei_response

iv) ei_sent_date
```

I am comparing the matri_id of register table to ei_sender and ei_receiver of expressinterest table, where one user can send requests to another users and he can receive request from another users.

I have to get the count of Pending, Accepted and Rejected status of all the users present in the register table, but when I am running the query it's running very slow, It takes around 45-60 seconds to fetch only 5000 rows in which the data is not proper (a single ID is coming in 3 rows like Accepted in one row, Rejected in one row and Pending in one row), But I want all the counts to come in a single row like this

```
r.matri_id | r._email | r.mobile | pending_count | accepted_ count | rejected_count| r.last_login
```

Some queries which I had tried so far are

```
select r.matri_id, r.email, r.mobile, r.last_login, e.receiver_response, count(e.receiver_response), e.ei_sender, e.ei_receiver from register r, expressinterest e where r.matri_id = e.ei_sender or r.matri_id = e.ei_receiver GROUP BY e.receiver_response, r.matri_id ORDER BY r.last_login DESC
```

**This is what I want but its taking 5-6 seconds to execute**

```
select matri_id, email, mobile, last_login, (select count(ei_sender) from expressinterest where ei_receiver=matri_id and receiver_response = 'Pending') AS pending_count_mine, 
(select count(ei_sender) from expressinterest where ei_sender=matri_id and receiver_response = 'Accepted') AS accepted_count,
(select count(ei_sender) from expressinterest where ei_sender=matri_id and receiver_response = 'Rejected') AS rejected_count FROM register ORDER BY last_login DESC
```

Thanks

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words for SQL questions.  If you had just shown sample input and output data your question would be a lot clearer.

Comment: Yes, But I had tried to make people understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the multiple correlated subqueries with a single subquery and a left join:

```
select r.matri_id,
    r.email,
    r.mobile,
    r.last_login,
    t.accepted_count,
    t.rejected_count,
    t.pending_count
from register r
left join (
    select ei_sender, 
        sum(receiver_response = 'Accepted') as accepted_count,
        sum(receiver_response = 'Rejected') as rejected_count,
        sum(receiver_response = 'Pending') as pending_count
    from expressinterest
    where receiver_response in ('Rejected', 'Accepted', 'Pending')
    group by ei_sender
    ) t on r.matri_id = t.ei_sender;
```